# How do I separate the post title from the content in an excerpt coded thus:

Tags: title, excerpt, blog-page

We're using a theme for a client that has programmed in their own excerpt & it's alright but it doesn't separate the title from the text in the excerpt itself, which is shown on the blog page. Here's the code:

```
function tt_excerpt( $id, $length = NULL ) {
    $length = !empty($length) ? $length : 55;
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
    $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    $content = substr($content, 0, $length);
    return $content.'...';
}
```

My PHP isn't nearly as strong as my CSS so I'm not entirely certain how to define the title in this excerpt code. I appreciate any insight!

Comment: With this theme, replacing the call for the custom excerpt with the_excerpt doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title isn't mentioned anywhere in that code, have they included it in the actual content?

If so, you could remove it using a str_replace:

```
$content = str_replace( get_the_title($id), '', $content);
```

Comment: Cheers, TCode! This, in conjunction with the_title in the right place was what was called for.